# Loading external custom fonts , into pdf documents using pdfbox in java

Tags: java, pdfbox, truetype, custom-font, pdf-parsing

I am targeting to read content with non built-in encoding using PDFBox.
[image: PDF document font properties]
As shown in the image, I am able to extract the text from PDF for all the fonts with **type TrueType and Encoding Built-in**.
I am getting sub encoded text as a result, in place of the content of **Type1 type and custom encoding**

I got following text
 !

and actually, text in the pdf is,
7.+13. DESCRIBE REACTION(s)

Is there anyway by which, we can make external font files available to pdf and force pdfbox to load these file into the document, so that we will get actual text present in the pdf.

Comment: Maybe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15964704/java-pdfbox-reading-and-modifying-a-pdf-with-special-characters-diacritics

Comment: Can you extract the text with Adobe Reader? If not, then you won't be able to do it with PDFBox. https://pdfbox.apache.org/2.0/faq.html#gibberish Also make sure you're using the latest version.

Comment: A "custom encoding" can be good and carry the information for text extraction but it also may be bad and not carry those information.